# compare two rows from same sqlite column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to update a column from a sqlite table with 1 if the previous row from a column is equal with the next row from the same column.

Exemple:

```
first_column | second_column
----------------------------
      a      |       0
      a      |       1
      b      |       0
      c      |       0
      c      |       1
```

My code:

```
UPDATE FROM my_table
SET second_column=1
WHERE first_column=first_column-1
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a *previous* or *next* row unless there is a column that sets the order of the rows. So is there a column like an `id` or `datetime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this table have a Primary Key? If not then you can create a table like:

```
create table new (colPK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, first_column, second_column);
```

Then in your update SQL you can use the use column colPK to reference the row number.

```
UPDATE FROM my_table tab1
SET tab1.second_column=1
WHERE tab1.first_column = ( SELECT tab2.first_column FROM my_table tab2 WHERE tab2.colPK-1 = tab1.colPK)
```